# Exporting current records on form to Excel on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

I have a form that allows a user to select a staff member and based on their selection, it will filter the records and only show that staff members. What I want to be able to do is have a button that will let me export this data that been filtered out to an Excel spreadsheet. I have no experience with exporting to excel on Laravel so I am completely stuck here. Could anyone give me a nudge in the right direction if you know.

I tried to use
 `public function collection() { return User::all(); }`
however this returns all the records to me.

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter the staff some identifier like a staff ID number?

Comment: no I want to export the records that show for the selected staff to an excel file @KrisStern